# How to access array of files from Laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, filepond

I have an Laravel request in which there is an array for uploaded files.
When doing `dd($request);` I get the following response for the request object.

```
+request: 
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#37 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "0YgPQyZ6fDvKfqohFzLTrV6GVs2xLmu60Vh2H3Je"
      "_method" => "post"
      "shortdescription" => "123"
      "department" => "IT"
      "description" => "123123"
      "files" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "ticket65af9c14d6e554.69690242"
        1 => "ticket65af9c14b43675.72479216"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

How can I access the files inside Laravel? I already tried the following things:

```
$allFiles = $request->files->all();
$allFiles = $request->allFiles();
$allFiles = $request->files->get('files');
$allFiles = $request->file('files');
```

When I try to `dd($allFiles);` they are just NULL
Where am I going wrong here? I can not figure it out how to access these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
$files = Input::file('request')[files]; foreach($files as $file) { $file; }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this!! After your answer I too saw that the request is an InputBug and therefore I had to access the input variable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after https://stackoverflow.com/users/23286287/bhumika-khakhadiya

Got me on the right track.

```
    $files = $request->input('files');
    $tmpFiles = TemporaryFile::whereIn('folder', $files)->get();
    $folderNames = $tmpFiles->pluck('folder')->toArray();
```

With that I now have access to the foldernames!